# How to integrate SIP into Android?

Tags: android, sip, voip, rtp, sdp

How to implement SIP protocol in Android ?
there is any SDK or library available to implement it easily into Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/DoubangoTelecom/imsdroid) is a third party Library with sample code. You can use this, I have used it and it works fine.

Comment: I need a clarification why to use this library?? As @Priyank mentioned Android 2.3 supports API for SIP and the sip stack is available what is the advantage of using this library ???

Answer (score 3):

**Android 2.3** or higher provides API for SIP.

Refer this link for [SIP in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html)

also you can see DEMO project for SIP from [Sample](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html)

**update:**
Android SDK Samples on github.
[SipDemo1](https://github.com/Miserlou/Android-SDK-Samples/tree/master/SipDemo), [SipDemo2](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_development/tree/master/samples/SipDemo)

Comment: Some carriers disable the native SIP in Android, and some tablets don't support it.  Also, older Android versions don't support SIP.

Comment: @HankKarl as you said some carrier disable the native SIP support can i  do get it by using my WIFI????

Answer (score 1):

Search for SipDemo project in samples for android 4.0.3 SDK version(API level -15)

Comment: But this SIPDemo has serious problem, i am not able to register my SIP profile ,its always showing registration failed error do you have any idea how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

I have been investigated this sort of problem for a long time and found out that [SipManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager) and [SipProfile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipProfile) are unfortunatelly poor and extremelly buggy.

So I found a ***Linphone*** library. There is a [link](https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Lib/Getting%20started/Android/) for their wiki. I implemented it in my project using *maven*:

```
repositories {
    ...
    maven { "https://linphone.org/maven_repository/"}
}
```

Also there is a sample of using it on gitlab: [link here](https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-android/tree/11b223c0dcbdb2f7bc8fad3f94005a0c29aa33e9/sample), it's pretty fresh, for now :)

If the link would crash, I just copy/paste the most important part of how to use ***linphone***'s core:

```java
public class LinphoneService extends Service {
    private static final String START_LINPHONE_LOGS = " ==== Device information dump ====";
    // Keep a static reference to the Service so we can access it from anywhere in the app
    private static LinphoneService sInstance;

    private Handler mHandler;
    private Timer mTimer;

    private Core mCore;
    private CoreListenerStub mCoreListener;

    public static boolean isReady() {
        return sInstance != null;
    }

    public static LinphoneService getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    public static Core getCore() {
        return sInstance.mCore;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // The first call to liblinphone SDK MUST BE to a Factory method
        // So let's enable the library debug logs & log collection
        String basePath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        Factory.instance().setLogCollectionPath(basePath);
        Factory.instance().enableLogCollection(LogCollectionState.Enabled);
        Factory.instance().setDebugMode(true, getString(R.string.app_name));

        // Dump some useful information about the device we're running on
        Log.i(START_LINPHONE_LOGS);
        dumpDeviceInformation();
        dumpInstalledLinphoneInformation();

        mHandler = new Handler();
        // This will be our main Core listener, it will change activities depending on events
        mCoreListener = new CoreListenerStub() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(Core core, Call call, Call.State state, String message) {
                Toast.makeText(LinphoneService.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (state == Call.State.IncomingReceived) {
                    Toast.makeText(LinphoneService.this, "Incoming call received, answering it automatically", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // For this sample we will automatically answer incoming calls
                    CallParams params = getCore().createCallParams(call);
                    params.enableVideo(true);
                    call.acceptWithParams(params);
                } else if (state == Call.State.Connected) {
                    // This stats means the call has been established, let's start the call activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LinphoneService.this, CallActivity.class);
                    // As it is the Service that is starting the activity, we have to give this flag
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };

        try {
            // Let's copy some RAW resources to the device
            // The default config file must only be installed once (the first time)
            copyIfNotExist(R.raw.linphonerc_default, basePath + "/.linphonerc");
            // The factory config is used to override any other setting, let's copy it each time
            copyFromPackage(R.raw.linphonerc_factory, "linphonerc");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e(ioe);
        }

        // Create the Core and add our listener
        mCore = Factory.instance()
                .createCore(basePath + "/.linphonerc", basePath + "/linphonerc", this);
        mCore.addListener(mCoreListener);
        // Core is ready to be configured
        configureCore();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        // If our Service is already running, no need to continue
        if (sInstance != null) {
            return START_STICKY;
        }

        // Our Service has been started, we can keep our reference on it
        // From now one the Launcher will be able to call onServiceReady()
        sInstance = this;

        // Core must be started after being created and configured
        mCore.start();
        // We also MUST call the iterate() method of the Core on a regular basis
        TimerTask lTask =
                new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mHandler.post(
                                new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if (mCore != null) {
                                            mCore.iterate();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                };
        mTimer = new Timer("Linphone scheduler");
        mTimer.schedule(lTask, 0, 20);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mCore.removeListener(mCoreListener);
        mTimer.cancel();
        mCore.stop();
        // A stopped Core can be started again
        // To ensure resources are freed, we must ensure it will be garbage collected
        mCore = null;
        // Don't forget to free the singleton as well
        sInstance = null;

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        // For this sample we will kill the Service at the same time we kill the app
        stopSelf();

        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    private void configureCore() {
        // We will create a directory for user signed certificates if needed
        String basePath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        String userCerts = basePath + "/user-certs";
        File f = new File(userCerts);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            if (!f.mkdir()) {
                Log.e(userCerts + " can't be created.");
            }
        }
        mCore.setUserCertificatesPath(userCerts);
    }

    private void dumpDeviceInformation() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("DEVICE=").append(Build.DEVICE).append("\n");
        sb.append("MODEL=").append(Build.MODEL).append("\n");
        sb.append("MANUFACTURER=").append(Build.MANUFACTURER).append("\n");
        sb.append("SDK=").append(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT).append("\n");
        sb.append("Supported ABIs=");
        for (String abi : Version.getCpuAbis()) {
            sb.append(abi).append(", ");
        }
        sb.append("\n");
        Log.i(sb.toString());
    }

    private void dumpInstalledLinphoneInformation() {
        PackageInfo info = null;
        try {
            info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException nnfe) {
            Log.e(nnfe);
        }

        if (info != null) {
            Log.i(
                    "[Service] Linphone version is ",
                    info.versionName + " (" + info.versionCode + ")");
        } else {
            Log.i("[Service] Linphone version is unknown");
        }
    }

    private void copyIfNotExist(int ressourceId, String target) throws IOException {
        File lFileToCopy = new File(target);
        if (!lFileToCopy.exists()) {
            copyFromPackage(ressourceId, lFileToCopy.getName());
        }
    }

    private void copyFromPackage(int ressourceId, String target) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream lOutputStream = openFileOutput(target, 0);
        InputStream lInputStream = getResources().openRawResource(ressourceId);
        int readByte;
        byte[] buff = new byte[8048];
        while ((readByte = lInputStream.read(buff)) != -1) {
            lOutputStream.write(buff, 0, readByte);
        }
        lOutputStream.flush();
        lOutputStream.close();
        lInputStream.close();
    }
}
```

I hope, that will help somebody, because I spend a lot of time trying to find it!

Answer (score 0):

I used by this library:
https://www.mizu-voip.com/Software/SIPSDK/AndroidSIPSDK.aspx
it is very easy.
also i add button for answer the call:

```
mysipclient.Accept(mysipclient.GetLine());
```